# ruby on rails rename nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following routes

```
resources :posts, path: :blog do
    resources :comments, path: :comments do
    end
  end


  devise_scope :user do
    resources :posts, path: :blog do
      resources :comments do

      end
    end
  end
```

this gives me

```
post_comments GET    /news/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /news/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /news/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_post_comment GET    /news/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment GET    /news/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PATCH  /news/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  PUT    /news/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /news/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            posts GET    /news(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /news(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET    /news/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET    /news/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET    /news/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PATCH  /news/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  PUT    /news/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /news/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
                  GET    /news/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /news/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
                  GET    /news/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
                  GET    /news/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
                  GET    /news/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PATCH  /news/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  PUT    /news/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /news/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
                  GET    /news(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /news(.:format)                            posts#create
                  GET    /news/new(.:format)                        posts#new
                  GET    /news/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                  GET    /news/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PATCH  /news/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  PUT    /news/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /news/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
             root GET    /                                          posts#index
```

1. why are there routes multiple routes that are exactly the same?
2. how do i rename for example the news/edit to news update inside a nested resource?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you are calling resources for posts, path, blog and comments multiple times, you are just changing the order, but the links will be the same.